# retrieving user input from a text field

Tags: input

What is the best way to retrieve user-input text from a text field on Submit button press?  I am having issues with the listener, because it doesn't return anything (located in my gui class).  I need to somehow retrieve what the user inputs, then return to the main class, and decide from there what to do with the user input.  an example code would be nice!

Comment: input in what? you need to provide some context. is this web/winforms/ruby/php/something else?

Comment: Can you use Boost, or is this an XML/CSS project?

Answer (score 1):

You can attach a listener with your button and override its actionPerformed(). Inside actionPerformed(), you can retrieve the value entered in the text field.
Something like this :

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener (){

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
   String text = textField.getText();
 }
};)
```